In vue, is it possible to turn the slot's content into a template and render it?
I am trying to create a component in which the slot itself gets turned into a template and rendered. In this case:
<template>
  <slottable>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Uno</th><th>Due</th></tr>
      <tr><td>uno</td><td>due</td></tr>
    </table>
  </slottable>
  </div>
</template>

Where I'd like the table element to be parsed and the second row to be used as a template to be repeated for a number of rows.
I managed to parse it and convert it into a string looking like this:
<table>
   <tr><th>Uno</th><th>Due</th></tr>
   <tr v-for="(i, r) in rows"><td>{{ uno }}</td><td>{{ due }}</td></tr>
</table>

At this point I'd like to use this as a template with this data:
    data: function () {
    return {
        rows: [
        { uno: 1, due: 2 },
        { uno: "I", due: "II" },
        { uno: "i", due: "ii" },
        { uno: "one", due: "two" },
        
        ]
    };
    },

I am aware of this answer but it seems to require that the template is a predefined string, whereas I am trying to do that with the content of the slot - which doesn't exist at the point at which the render function is defined.
Is that possible? I am using vue2

Consider explaining your case, it's unclear how it is supposed to work. A comp with  in the template would behave as you describe

@EstusFlask - done, I hope it helps

<tr v-for="(i, r) in rows" is the way it's supposed to be written. Is there a specific reason you need it to be like <tr><td>uno</td><td>due</td></tr>? You can process slot's vnodes in render function to achieve a result similar to v-for but this will require you to hard-code the second  to be iterated, this doesn't look beneficial. In case you want it to be more flexible and data-driven,  a design like this one usually involves slot props, so it would be used something like <mytable :data="rows"><template #head>...</template><template #row="rowProps"><tr><td>{{rowProps.uno}}</td>...

Didn't know about the template tag. Will try that
